# How to change form action thru if else statement on PHP?

Tags: php, forms, action

**How I can change the form action thru if else statement that will redirect to other PHP page?
I'm new to PHP, thankyou in advance**

here is my code:

```
                <?php
            if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
            {
                $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
                $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];

                $sel = "SELECT Lname FROM users WHERE Fname='" . $Fname . "'";
                $result = $conn->query($sel);
                if($result->num_rows>0)
                {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $Lname = $row['Lname'];
                    }
                    if ($Lname == $Lname) 
                    {
                        echo "Correct data!";
                        /*i want to put redirect page here*/
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "invalid Firsname!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "invalid Lastname!";
                }
            }
            ?>

                   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                        <input type="text"  name="Fname" placeholder="Enter your Fname" required>
                        <input type="text"  name="Lname" placeholder="Lname" required>
                        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Sign In">
                   </form>
```

Comment: Google "php redirect" - It was asked and explained like a million times already

Comment: Hi Leouie, your form will send its data to the URL you specify in the action attribute of the form tag in your HTML. In this case, you ask the form to be submitted to what ever value you have in the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] variable. If you wanted to send the form to a different page than the current one, you could change that to something else (ie: echo "/page2.php"). Your question is getting voted to be closed because you are not really explaining what is wrong with your current code I think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

example

```
if ($_POST['p'] == 1) {  $insertGoTo = "t1.php"; }
if ($_POST['p'] == 2) {  $insertGoTo = "t2.php"; }

  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
```

?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.